# Google api v3 - From Info Window to json txt file: Saving User-Added Form Data

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps-api-3

I make google map api v3. I want to make saving user-added form data by clicking on the marker, it appears info window, info window contains form data, then data added will be saved in json txt file.
Here is map.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var marker;
    var infowindow;

    function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.9667, 110.41677);
      var options = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
      var html = "<table>" +
             "<tr> <td> Title:</td> <td><input type='text' name='title' id='title'/> </td> </tr>  " +
         "<tr> <td> Description:</td> <td><input type='text' name='description' id='description'/> </td> </tr> " +
         "<tr> <td> Category:</td> <td><input type='text' name='category' id='category'/> </td> </tr> " +
             "<tr> <td></td> <td> <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick='saveData()' /> </td> </tr> ";
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: html
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    });
    }

    function saveData() {
      var title = escape(document.getElementById("title").value);
      var description = escape(document.getElementById("description").value);
      var category = escape(document.getElementById("category").value);
      var latlng = marker.getPosition();

      var url = "save_json.php?title=" + title + "&description=" + description +
            "&category=" + category + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
      downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
    if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
      infowindow.close();
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
    }
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"></div>
    <div id="message"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is save_json.php

```
<?php
    // Append new form data in json string saved in text file

    // path and name of the file
$filetxt = 'dirdata/data.txt';

    // check if all form data are submited, else output error message
    if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['category'])) {
    // if form fields are empty, outputs message, else, gets their data
    if(empty($_POST['title']) || empty($_POST['lat']) || empty($_POST['lng']) || empty($_POST['description']) || empty($_POST['category'])) {
        echo 'All fields are required';
    }
    else {
    // gets and adds form data into an array
    $data = array(
      'title'=> $_POST['title'],
      'lat'=> (float) $_POST['lat'],
      'lng'=> (float) $_POST['lng'],
      'description'=> $_POST['description'],
      'category'=> $_POST['category'],
    );

    // path and name of the file
    $filetxt = 'dirdata/data.txt';

    $arr_data = array();        // to store all form data

    // check if the file exists
    if(file_exists($filetxt)) {
      // gets json-data from file
      $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);

      // converts json string into array
      $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    }

    // appends the array with new form data
    $arr_data[] = $data;

    // encodes the array into a string in JSON format (JSON_PRETTY_PRINT - uses whitespace in json-string, for human readable)
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    // saves the json string in "data.txt" (in "dirdata" folder)
    // outputs error message if data cannot be saved
    if(file_put_contents('dirdata/data.txt', $jsondata)) echo 'Data successfully saved';
    else echo 'Tidak dapat menyimpan data di "dirdata/data.txt"';
  }
}
    else echo 'Form fields not submited';
?>
```

The data should be saved in data.txt like this, but it it doesn't work

```
[
    {
    "title": "title",
    "lat": -6.9000,
    "lng": -110.000,
    "description": "description",
    "category": "category"
    }
]
```

Anyone can help me how to make it correct? Thank you very much for any help

Comment: *make it correct* ...what currently doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Have u tried the code? I think the problem is save_json.php
There is no respon from map html, data added not sent to data.txt